# Is there a way to generate equal sized clusters of GPS coordinates in PHP

Tags: php, maps, k-means

**The Problem**

I have lists of GPS coordinates, these coordinates correspond to houses in the same area of a town/city. Each list of coordinates will have a team assigned to it. I would like the team to visit every house in the list, so I would like each team member to visit the roughly the same amount of houses

So I would like to assign an equal sized subset of this list to each team member. So the clusters obviously need to group coordinates close together. I know because I need equal sized clusters that they won't be perfect, but it is more important to me that they are of the same size.

**The Setup**

I think in Python I could use [k-means-constrained](https://pypi.org/project/k-means-constrained/), so that I can declare a min & max size of my clusters, but I cannot find anything similar in PHP. I also cannot wrap my head around adapting standard k-means to do what I want.

I know I will not get perfect clusters, but it is more important to me that they are all of roughly equal size, than how good the clusters are.

**Question**

If someone has implemented something to do what I want could you please link me, as I haven't found anything similar in PHP. Or maybe I am looking at the problem in the wrong way, so if anyone has any suggestions they would be very welcome.

Thanks.